# Predictive model for categorical data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models

I have a data with majority of data being binary(0&1) and I would like to predict a numerical outcome time. All the columns are anonymized; Size columns:385, rows:4209. Can anyone suggest what predictive model should I use and how should I transform the data to use in model?

I have tried Neural networks, but it could explain only 48% of variability. Also tried Simple regression, it does not give good results. I am looking to Xgboost and catboost for improving the prediction. Any suggestions?

Example:

`X1 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)
X2 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
X3 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)
X4 <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1)
X5 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)
y <- c(130,59,84,77,69,91,86,104,99,68)`

Comment: Random Forest is my go-to.  It works the best out of the box with minimal tuning, usually.  Use this for prediction, along with LASSO and (pruned) CART trees for developing intuition.  This is general advice.  Anything more specific will depending on your particular data and problem.

Comment: I will try your option!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a few more option on top of those @generic_user suggest.

You can try the `mboost` package in R for gradient boosting (e.g., use `blackboost` to boost tress). You may find that a specific `family` is well suited for your problem.

You can try a penalized `glm`. You can try `cv.glmnet` from the `glmnet` package to find the penalty factor with cross validation. You can use the `alpha` parameter to choose between an L1, L2 or elastic net penalty. Again, you can choose the `family` to pick the likelihood function to optimize.

Comment: I will try your solutions...actually I am working on Kaggle problem [Mercedes greener manufacturing](https://www.kaggle.com/c/mercedes-benz-greener-manufacturing). I am doing this as a project and I need a simpler model to explain the guide.This should help me.